# How to extract info from a text file using a function. Python 3

Tags: python, list, file, io, tuples

'Have been up for ages so sorry if I'm not clear.
Basically the task I have to do, like a query for databases I have there is an external text file which contains info.
User will query for a criteria and I should be able to return with info.

For example:

```
Text file = 

RegNo **' Year'**

53245   **'3'** GH4P Richard Steel

35134 **'2'** G400A Anub Fankool

etc
```

So the 3 and 2 go under the Year header.
I want to write a program were the user will input what year they want to retrieve.

For example `Year 2` then it will retrieve the `data: 35134 2 G400A Anub Fankool`.

Need to do the same with `Regno` and `name`.

Just need to be pushed in the right direction so I can start/finish this.

Thanks.

code so far:

```
def order_name(regno, year, course, first_name, middle_name, last_name=None):
    if not last_name:
            last_name = middle_name
    else:
            first_name = "%s %s"  % (first_name, middle_name)
    return ("%s, %s" % (last_name, first_name), regno, course, year)
```

Comment: ISs the year in quotes?

Comment: please show us what have you tried?

Comment: No the Year is not in quotes. Just put that there to make it clear for you guys.

Comment: I have no clue how to go about this, That is the thing. I have this code here. (Updated post) I'm thinking of using the year in the function to narrow results down but this is all in my head and don't know how to code it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s =""" 53245 3 GH4P Richard Steel\n35134 2 G400A Anub Fankool"""
x="2"
print re.findall(r"^(?=\d+\s+"+x+"\s+).*$",s,re.MULTILINE)
```

You can try something like this using `re` module.